# Parse base64 text after second blank line perl

Tags: perl, email

I'm new in perl. I have an old script that parsing text in e-mail message for sending it in sms via smstools on Centos Server. We add another software, for which we must use sms informing in cyrillic. 
Old software sends emails in format:

```
Headers
Headers
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
blank line
BASE64 TEXT
```

and script correctly parsing and decoding BASE64 TEXT.
New software sends emails in format:

```
Headers
Headers
blank line
------=_Part_digits
Header
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
blank line
BASE64 TEXT
```

and script cannot correctly parse BASE64 TEXT. 
The function for parsing text for sms is:

```
sub Process_Email
{
    my ($Sms_To,@Lines)=@_;
    my $Body_Start ="False";
    my $Sms_Body = "";
    my $Base64="False";
    my $HTML_Mess="False";
    my $HTML_Text="False";
    my $Boundary;
        # Declare local variables
    my ($From, $Line);
        # Check each line in the header
    foreach $Line (@Lines)
        {
        if($Line =~ m/^From: (.*)/)
            {
            $From = lc($1);
            $From =~ s/.*<|>|@[a-z].*//g;
            &Write_Log("From = $From");
            }
        elsif( $Line =~ m/^Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64(.*)/)
            {
                 $Base64="True";
                &Write_Log("Message was encoded in base64");
            }
        elsif( $Line =~ m/Content-Type: multipart\/alternative(.*)/)
            {
                $HTML_Mess="True";
                &Write_Log("The message in HTML format");
                if($Line =~ m/boundary=\"(.*)/)
                    {
                        my $PosStart = index($Line,'"');
                        $PosStart++;
                         my $PosEnd = rindex($Line,'"');
                          my $PosLeight = $PosEnd-$PosStart;
                       $Boundary = substr($Line,$PosStart,$PosLeight);
                       $Boundary =~ s/\+|\-|\=//g;
                    }
            }
        elsif(($Line =~ m/boundary=\"(.*)/)&&($HTML_Mess eq "True"))
            {
            my $PosStart=index($Line,'"');
            $PosStart++;
            my $PosEnd=rindex($Line,'"');
            my $PosLeight=$PosEnd-$PosStart;
            $Boundary=substr($Line,$PosStart,$PosLeight);
            $Boundary =~ s/\+|\-|\=//g;
            }
        elsif( $Line =~ m/Content-Type: multipart\/mixed(.*)/)
            {
                $HTML_Mess="True";
                &Write_Log("The message in HTML format");
                       if($Line =~ m/boundary=\"(.*)/)
                    {
                    my $PosStart = index($Line,'"');
                    $PosStart++;
                    my $PosEnd = rindex($Line,'"');
                    my $PosLeight = $PosEnd-$PosStart;
                    $Boundary = substr($Line,$PosStart,$PosLeight);
                    $Boundary =~ s/\+|\-|\=//g;
                    }
            }
        elsif(($Line =~ m/boundary=\"(.*)/)&&($HTML_Mess eq "True"))
            {
            my $PosStart=index($Line,'"');
            $PosStart++;
            my $PosEnd=rindex($Line,'"');
            my $PosLeight=$PosEnd-$PosStart;
            $Boundary=substr($Line,$PosStart,$PosLeight);
            $Boundary =~ s/\+|\-|\=//g;
            }
            # find blank line
        elsif($Line =~ /^\n$/)
            {
            $Body_Start="True";
            next;
            }
            # Begins sms body
        if($Body_Start eq "True")
            {
                # decode BASE64 TEXT
            if($Base64 eq "True") 
{ 
           $Sms_Body=$Sms_Body . decode_base64($Line);
}
            elsif($HTML_Mess eq "True")
                {
                if($HTML_Text eq "True")
                    {
                    if($Line !~ m/$Boundary/)
                        {
                        $Sms_Body = $Sms_Body . $Line;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        $HTML_Text="False";
                        last;
                        }
                    }
                if(($Line =~ m/Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit/)&&($HTML_Text eq "False"))
                    {
                        $HTML_Text="True";
                    }
                }
            else { $Sms_Body = $Sms_Body . $Line; }
            }
        }
```

When I have email with one blank line this function working well. 
But if in email two blank lines BASE64 TEXT is parsing with upper headers and I receive wrong result. How can I correctly parse fragment of BASE64 TEXT with minimal editing of original code?

Comment: How about using a MIME parser?

Comment: I see you're calling subs with `&`. Using `&` hasn't been necessary since 1994, when perl5 was released.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading from STDIN or an input, how about something like this?

```
while ( <> ) { 
   last if m/^$/; # blank line;
   my ( $header, $value ) = split /:/; 
}


my $mime_content = do { local $/; <> }; #read rest of input. 
#then decode it, etc.
```

Comment: I edited my answer and add full function for parsing BASE64 TEXT. Please review it, and leave advice with minimal correction of original text.